# Printing in next line in a VB.NET Label

Tags: vb.net, label

This is my code:

```
Private Sub btn_Validate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Validate.Click
    Call ValidateData(txt_score1.Text, "1")
    Call ValidateData(txt_score2.Text, "2")
    Call ValidateData(txt_score3.Text, "3")
    Call ValidateData(txt_score4.Text, "4")
End Sub

Private Sub ValidateData(ByVal vScore As String, ByVal vintScore As String)
    If (vScore = "") Then
        lbl_StatusContent.Text = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is blank"
    ElseIf Not (IsNumeric(vScore)) Then
        lbl_StatusContent.Text = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is not numeric"
    ElseIf (vScore < 0 And vScore > 10) Then
        lbl_StatusContent.Text = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is not in range: 0-10"
    Else
        lbl_StatusContent.Text = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is Valid"

    End If
    vintScore = vintScore + 1
End Sub
```

The problem is that it is only showing my Score 4 result. Score1, Score 2, and Score 3 are being overlapped by the fourth one.

I want all them in next lines. So that I can see all the 4 Scores and no one is overlapped.

Comment: Use += to append text.  This is a fairly ugly way to validate data entry, favor the ErrorProvider component.

Comment: @HansPassant I think that &= would be more idiomatic for appending strings in VB.Net.  The += operator can have some unexpected effects depending on what is being appended.

Answer (score 0):

> **I want all them in next lines.**

I think you are looking for `vbnewline`  or [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you see only the last result. Every time you call the method you overwrite the previous output. I think you need something to concatenate the results and print all together

```
Private Sub btn_Validate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Validate.Click
    Dim result As String 
    result = ValidateData(txt_score1.Text, "1")
    result = result & ValidateData(txt_score2.Text, "2")
    result = result & ValidateData(txt_score3.Text, "3")
    result = result & ValidateData(txt_score4.Text, "4")
    lbl_StatusContent.Text = result
End Sub

Private Function ValidateData(ByVal vScore As String, ByVal vintScore As String) As String
    Dim result As String
    If (vScore = "") Then
        result = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is blank"
    ElseIf Not (IsNumeric(vScore)) Then
        result = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is not numeric"
    ElseIf (vScore < 0 And vScore > 10) Then
        result = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is not in range: 0-10"
    Else
        result = vbCrLf & "Score " & vintScore & " is Valid"
    End If
    return result
End Function
```

And be sure that the lbl_StatusContext.Height is enough to accomodate at least 4 lines of text

Comment: it says "Return statement in a Sub cannot return a value"

Comment: Oh okay it's a function. Can't we achieve the same thing in a SUb?

Comment: Well, you could concatenate the text inside your original Sub using `lbl_StatusContent.Text = lbl_StatusContent.Text & .....` but I prefer the Function approach for clarity